# how to make player hit an obstacle and move away (java)

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-development

here is my code for when my player intersects a GRect, but it only works for 2 sides of the rect. The other 2 give an undesirable effect.

```
private void gameLoop() {
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {

        if (pan.getBounds().intersects(b.getBounds())) {

            pan.move(-10, -10);
        }
```

How can i make my player "see" the rect as an obstacle and collide with it? 
I am using key listeners to move the player.

**EDIT**

i added the following if statements to check for interactions of the player with each side of the obstacle, but it again seems to work for **left and bottom** sides. I need **all four sides**.

I am using `pan.move` because it is what i use to move the player in the first place, when a key is pressed. So for example when i click left, i use `pan.move(-10,0)` and so to prevent the player from moving left i use `pan.move(10,0)`

```
    if (pan.getBounds().intersects(b1.getBounds())) {


        if ((pan.getX() +PAN_WIDTH ) > b1.getX()) {  // left
            pan.move(-10, 0);

        }
        if ((pan.getY() PAN_WIDTH ) > b1.getY()) {  //top
            pan.move(0, -10);

        }
        if ((pan.getY()) < b1.getY() + OBSTACLE_WIDTH) { // bottom
            pan.move(0, 10);

        }
        if ((pan.getX() PAN_WIDTH) < b1.getX() + OBSTACLE_HEIGHT) {  // right
            pan.move(10, 0);

        }
        }
```

Comment: You're always moving towards the left and up whenever a collision happens, irrespective of the side, which was hit. So even if you hit from the right side of the `GRect` you will move towards your left

Comment: I think you shouldn't move your player. Instead, if x position of right side from player is bigger than x position of left side of your obstacle, then you should be sure your player can't move right. For example, your player can have a `xMove` and `yMove` representing the future move of the player (based on the key input). Then, if you have a collision, just set the `xMove` or `yMove` to zero.

Comment: @Lutzi i see, but how could i figure out the left  and right positions of the objects?

Comment: Well, you certainly have a `x` and `y` position for these objects, don't you ?

Comment: @Lutzi i edited the code, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I can't help you without knowing what you've done so far ... but rightly coded, it should work perfectly.

Comment: @Lutzi could you please take a look at the code i provided in the edit, i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problem with your code, here is some corrections. You're messing up with `width` and `height` But without knowing all of your code, I don't guarantee that your way of doing it is okay.

```
if (pan.getBounds().intersects(b1.getBounds())) {

    if ((pan.getX() + pan.getWidth()) > b1.getX()) {  // left
        pan.move(-10, 0);
    } else if (pan.getX() < (b1.getX() + b1.getWidth())) { // right
        pan.move(10,0);
    }

    if ((pan.getY() + pan.getHeight()) > b1.getY()) {  //top
        pan.move(0, -10);
    } else if (pan.getY() < (b1.getY() + b1.getHeight())) { // bottom
        pan.move(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest you to change your constant to methods like `getWidth()`. In the case you change the dimensions of your obstacle or player, you'll not have to change the constants too.

Also, moving your player is not a good way of doing it. Your player should have two fields representing the moves you'll perform. Then in the case of collision, you just have to put these fields to 0. You don't want your player to move when collision, you just want it to stop going more left/right/up/down.

For example if you change the speed of your player, then you'll have to change all of these `pan()` manually. That's going to get you problems if you don't realize that.